# How to limit a number from a cell to x decimal points?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets Script, how do I stop limit a number to e.g. 3 decimal points?

For instance, the following code is a section of a function I have created which will send an email of the number in cell 'Q12', however the number I receive is e.g. 1.9468186134852794% instead of 1.94%.

```
var changeCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheetname").getRange("Q12");
var change = changeCell.getValue();
var changeFixed = change.toFixed(3);
```

Thanks

Comment: Provide [mcve].

Comment: You are not changing the cell value here, just the variable. Call the setValue(value) method on the Range object to see changes in the spreadsheet. Your code seems incomplete though

Comment: Does this topic help [Google Sheet Script Editor - how would one format their numbers properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54997529/1330560)

Answer (score 2):

```
function fixingDecimalPlaces() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var v=73.123456789;
  sh.getRange('A1').setValue(Number(v).toFixed(3));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send the value in `Q12` as it is shown in the sheet (with the same number of decimals), you can use [getDisplayValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValue()):

```js
var changeCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheetname").getRange("Q12");
var change = changeCell.getDisplayValue();
```

This won't change the value in the spreadsheet. If you want to do that, just use [setValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue):

```js
var changeCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheetname").getRange("Q12");
changeFixed = changeCell.getValue().toFixed(3);
changeCell.setValue(changeFixed);
```

#### Reference:

- [Range.getDisplayValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValue())
- [Range.setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)